# Change cross-reference name of enumerated items using cleveref

Tags: enumerate, enumitem, cleveref

I feel this is a really basic question, but I haven't figured out a solution after searching for half an hour so maybe other people will find this question useful as well.

I'm using the `cleveref` package for all my referencing needs. By default, when I reference say the first item of an enumerated list, the reference is displayed as `item 1`. However, I'd like the cross-reference name to be `part`, i.e. the reference should read `part 1`. I've been experimenting with the `\crefname` command, but

```
\crefname{item}{part}{parts}
```

doesn't do the trick. Does anyone know what I have to supply in the first argument to change the `\crefname` of items?

Here's a MWE to work with:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\item\label{item 1} Item 1.
\end{enumerate}

See \cref{item 1}.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Is that for a particular item, or do you want that `part` is associated to any reference to an enumerate item?

Comment: I want the name of every reference to an item to be `part`.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

cleveref use the counters as type. The counters of enumerate are enumi, enumii, enumiii enumiv: (I wouldn't use spaces in label names, so I removed it)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\crefname{enumi}{part}{parts}
\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\item\label{item1} Item 1.
\end{enumerate}

See \cref{item1}.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Damn it, why didn't I try that. :) Works great, thanks.